# combine page control + scrollview(includes imageviews) + textview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

[image]

I want to make an view that include; ScrollView,PageControl,TextView (As you see at pic)...

I have an NSArray that include img adress and text. So there is no problem take an image and its text and put them correctly. My problem is  I can'u use both of page control & scrollview that mean;

If I write code in

```
(IBAction)changePage:(id)sender //for valuechange event pagecontrol
```

pagecontrol is work correctly but scrolling not. Otherwise If I write code in

```
(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating
```

this time scrollworks but page control does not..

How can I combine them and work together correctly???

NOTE: 
These SS taken from IOS simulator that mean it works correctly not an image only. On interface there are 4 component;(correct order) navigation bar, scrollview,pagecontrol,textview.normally imageview does not exist ı add 1 of them on viewDidLoad() and others on changePage methods.

Answer (score 0):

in changePage method calculate the width of content and use scrollRectToVisible It works...

```
    CGRect frame;
    frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageController.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrViewNews scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```